# Pgpool - 3.5 configuration

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, performance, postgresql-9.2, enterprisedb, postgresql-performance

```
[enterprisedb@pgdvdb1dr bin]$ 2017-06-20 11:34:41: pid 103313: WARNING:  could not open configuration file: "pgpool.conf"

2017-06-20 11:34:41: pid 103313: DETAIL:  using default configuration parameter values
2017-06-20 11:34:41: pid 103313: FATAL:  initializing pool password, failed to open file:"/mnt/hgfs/edb-postgres.auto/pgpool/staging/linux-x64/pgpool/etc/pool_passwd"
2017-06-20 11:34:41: pid 103313: DETAIL:  file open failed with error:"No such file or directory"

[1]+  Exit 3                  ./pgpool -n
```

Comment: As error shows related to password error?

Comment: how to configure the pgpool in same server using different port and how to start and use the pgpool i need the steps can you ??????@Md Haidar Ali Khan

Comment: What is your O.S Environment?

Comment: rhel 7.2 and am getting same this error only

Comment: [enterprisedb@pgdvdb1dr bin]$ ./pgpool
2017-06-20 15:09:41: pid 2148: WARNING:  could not open configuration file: "pgpool.conf"

2017-06-20 15:09:41: pid 2148: DETAIL:  using default configuration parameter values

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up backend PostgreSQL servers for pgpool-II. These servers can be placed within the same host as pgpool-II, or on separate machines. If you decide to place the servers on the same host, different port numbers must be assigned for each server. If the servers are placed on separate machines, they must be configured properly so that they can accept network connections from pgpool-II.

if you will place two servers within the same host as pgpool-II, let's  suppose that you want to assign `5432`, `5433` port numbers respectively. To configure pgpool-II, edit `pgpool.conf` as follows.

```
backend_hostname0 = 'localhost'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_hostname1 = 'localhost'
backend_port1 = 5433
backend_weight1 = 1
```

For backend_hostname, backend_port, backend_weight, set the node's hostname, port number, and ratio for load balancing. At the end of each parameter string, node ID must be specified by adding positive integers starting with 0 `(i.e. 0, 1, 2, …)`.

`backend_weight` parameters are all `1`, meaning that SELECT queries are equally distributed Between two servers.

**Starting/Stopping pgpool**

```
$pgpool
```

The above command, however, prints no log messages because pgpool detaches the terminal. If you want to show pgpool log messages, you pass -n option to pgpool command so pgpool-II is executed as non-daemon process, and the terminal will not be detached.

```
$ pgpool -n &
```

The log messages are printed on the terminal, so the recommended options to use the following.

```
$ pgpool -n -d > /tmp/pgpool.log 2>&1 &
```

The -d option enables debug messages to be generated.

**To stop pgpool, execute the following command.**

```
$ pgpool stop
```

If any client is still connected, pgpool waits for it to disconnect, and then terminates itself. Run the following command instead if you want to shutdown pgpool forcibly.

```
$ pgpool -m fast stop
```

For further your ref [Here](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/tutorial-en.html)